# Lando+Xdebugで環境構築したが、xdebugが有効にならない

Tags: php, vscode, drupal

teratailでなかなか回答を得られないため、こちらでも質問しています。

**実現したいこと**
xdebugのクライアント接続を解決したい
xdebugを正常に稼働させたい

**前提**
LandoでDrupalの開発環境を構築し、開発のためxdebugを有効化させようとしましたが、
インストール等はうまくいっているものの、エラーメッセージが表示されそのエラーを解決できない

**発生している問題・エラーメッセージ**
xdebug.log

```
Xdebug: [Step Debug] Could not connect to debugging client. Tried: 172.22.169.144:9003 (fallback through xdebug.client_host/xdebug.client_port).
```

lando.yml

```
name: tesutosaito
recipe: drupal9
config:
  webroot: web
  # VS CodeでXdebugを使用する設定
  xdebug: true
# メールサーバーをサービスとして追加
services:
  mailhog:
    type: mailhog
    hogfrom:
     - appserver
  phpmyadmin:
    type: phpmyadmin
  appserver:
    xdebug: debug
    config:
      php: .vscode/php.ini
```

.vscode/php.ini

```
[PHP]
; Xdebug
xdebug.max_nesting_level = 256
xdebug.show_exception_trace = 0
xdebug.collect_params = 0
xdebug.mode = debug
xdebug.start_with_request = yes
xdebug.client_host = ${LANDO_HOST_IP}
xdebug.client_port = 9003
xdebug.log = xdebug.log

; Remote settings
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_autostart = 1
xdebug.remote_host = ${LANDO_HOST_IP}
; xdebug.remote_connect_back = 1
; xdebug.remote_log = /tmp/xdebug_remote.log
```

vscodeのDEBUGCONSOLEに帰ってきた内容

```
<- outputEvent
tS {
  seq: 0,
  type: 'event',
  event: 'output',
  body: {
    category: 'stdout',
    output: 'Listening to Xdebug on port 0.0.0.0:9003,:::9003 ...\n'
  }
}

Listening to Xdebug on port 0.0.0.0:9003,:::9003 ...
<- launchResponse
BE {
  seq: 0,
  type: 'response',
  request_seq: 2,
  command: 'launch',
  success: true
}
```

**試したこと**
標準的なインストール手順を実行
https://www.acquia.com/jp/blog/how-to-use-lando-for-building-drupal-local-environment
下記サイトよりxdebugがインストールされていることを確認
https://xdebug.org/wizard
php debug拡張機能をインストール、.lando.ymlを編集（このようにファイルを編集したところ、上記のDEBUG CONSOLE内容が帰ってきた）
https://thehigglers.com/blogs/2023-04-19-how-to-configure-xdebug-with-lando-for-drupal-development/

**補足情報（FW/ツールのバージョンなど）**
Landoを起動すると

```
You have version 24.0.2 but Lando wants something in the 18.09.3 - 20.10.99 range.
```

というwarningが出ますが、dockerをダウングレードすると他に影響が出るので、まずはそれ以外の方法を探しています。
Drupal 9.4
Docker version 24.0.2
Lando v3.6.5
Xdebug 3.2.1
PHP 8.1